# How to get plotted function value in python

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, scipy

I have 2 discrete coordinates, X and Y. I call `plt.plot(X,Y)` and get nice plot. Not I want to get the values of X(the X is that is not included in the file)  from that plot(function graphic). For example I have `X=[1,2,3,4] Y=[0.4,0.5, 0.8, 0.85]` how to get the value for `X` when `Y = 0.43 ?`

Comment: You'd have to interpolate (as your plot routine already does. linearly). Consider [numpy.interp](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.interp.html)

Comment: You need to be more specific - the values you specify are not linear, so do your want it to return Y according to a linear fit, polynomial fit, a trapezoidal fit, or something else. Also, please show your attempts to make it easier for us to help you.

Comment: I need to do trapezoidal fit

Comment: You need [scipy.optimize.leastsq](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.leastsq.html) to calculate the nearest value of k and b in statement`y=kx+b`.

Comment: That's not a `matplotlib` question, but a [`scipy`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/interpolate.html) or [`numpy`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.interp.html) one. Just [look for examples](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=python+interpolation).

Answer (score 2):

With numpy:

```
import numpy as np

X=[1,2,3,4]
Y=[0.4 ,0.5, 0.8, 0.85]

y = .43
x = np.interp(y, Y, X)
```

Without numpy:

```
X=[1,2,3,4]
Y=[0.4, 0.5, 0.8, 0.85]

y = .43

for i, yi in enumerate(Y):
    if y < yi:
        break

k = (X[i] - X[i-1])/(Y[i] - Y[i-1])
m = X[i-1]

x = k*(y-Y[i-1])+m
```

Note, that the function y = f(x) has to invertable (definite) and y has to be within the range of Y for this to work, as I haven't added any boundry checks.

What I do, is that I calculate the slope in the interesting region, and then use that to find the value at an offset from `Y[i-1]`